# Wi-fi problem after tablet stand by

Tags: wi-fi, connection-issues, standby

I have a couple of tablets for a school software.Tablets are mid 2.3 gingerbread. They work ok. When they start, it checks for wi-fi and automatically connects. My problem is, after 30 minutes of inactivity, when they get into stand-by, after I unlock the screen my wi-fi connection is not available. But if I turn off/on it works ok. I was wondering how can I fix this so that when the screen goes into stand-by when it wakes the wi-fi will work. (The tablets are in a different city and I can't turn the wi-fi on manually or by remote). Any help is welcomed. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Go to SETTINGS > WIRELESS > WIFI SETTINGS.

Press MENU > ADVANCED. Ensure the WiFi Sleep Policy is set to NEVER. This will make sure that your WiFi remains always connected. This may however result in a marginal increase in battery consumption.

Comment: In that case, a brief search would have turned up similar answers. :-)